# Angular/Material2 Show matTooltip in mat-datepicker on unavailable dates

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

What would be the best approach to implementing an matTooltip that is dependent on unavailable dates using mat-datepicker in Angular Material2?

https://stackblitz.com/angular/ynepeydnykp

Comment: You want a MatTooltip to be show on hover after an invalid date has been entered or you want the tooltip to be automatically displayed on wrong date ?

Comment: I wish that when I mouse over an invalid date, I'll show a custom tooltip

Answer (score -1):

Ok then here is the forked [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/ynepeydnykp)

we will use the [matTooltipDisabled](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/api#MatTooltip) @Input to achieve that.

In the template, we add a reference to the date model to be able to check for validity.

And if it's valid, then we disable the tooltip.

Comment: My goal is to do something like this in Material 2, but assign the tooltip from programming (every day has a different tooltip)

https://codepen.io/loenko/pen/PEzdQv

Will it be possible?

Comment: ok i see your needs now. I think it will be tricky. You could dynamize the codepen with the attr() css function ( see here => https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/attr ) but you will have to find a way to add custom attributes on disabled date.